How to use "LIKE" in Pyspark SQL expression statement
I would like to create a filter with SQL expression statement that will help me to exclude rows from PySaprk dataframe, where column "file_path" fits the pattern "c:\part1\part2\part3\*".
SO basically the code should look like this:
df = spark.createDataFrame(["c:\somepath","d:\somepath","c:\part1\part2\part3\something1","c:\part1\part2\part3\something2"], "string").toDF("file_path")

path_filter = "NOT (file_path like 'c:\part1\part2\part3\%')"  
df_filtered = df.filter(path_filter) #should keep only the first 2 rows from df

I've been trying with different combinations (escaping, raw literals etc) but could not find the solution.
Without escaping, I'm still getting the same number of rows as before the filtration.
With escaping I'm receiving the error "The escape character is not allowed to precede 'p'"

Without a minimal reproducible example I cannot test it myself quickly, but I think you need to escape the backslashes either 3 or 4 times to account for both python and sql escaping rules. Could you try 'c:\\part1\\part2\\part3\\%' and see what it says?

I was trying this escaping with "\" ('c:\\part1\\part2\\part3\%') and "\\" ('c:\\part1\\part2\\part3\\%') but Im getting the same error: The escape character is not allowed to precede 'p'

I've also added some sample code (PySpark df creation) to reproduce the error.

Try a raw string with 4 backslashes, path_filter = r"NOT file_path LIKE 'c:\\\\part1\\\\part2\\\\part3\\\\%'" as Patrick F suggested. It seems like there is some double escaping going on, but not on the python level as we're using raw strings.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You need to pass a python raw string to spark sql and escape the backslashes. Another way would be using the regex_expr from the spark functions module which is more powerful.
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
data  =[
    "c:\somepath",
    "d:\somepath",
    "c:\part1\part2\part3\something1",
    "c:\part1\part2\part3\something2"
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, "string").toDF("file_path")
escapor = r"\\\\"
path_filter = rf"file_path not like 'c:{escapor}part1{escapor}part2{escapor}part3{escapor}%'"
df_filtered = df.filter(f.expr(path_filter)) #should keep only the first 2 rows from df
df_filtered.show()


Result:
+-----------+
|  file_path|
+-----------+
|c:\somepath|
|d:\somepath|
+-----------+

